# How to subtract the smallest from the largest number until 0 is left

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function that would keep subtracting the smallest from the largest number, replacing the largest number with the output of the subtraction until it gets to 0. So for instance, the input 5,3 should return 3,2,1,1. But my code doesn't give any output. How can this function be improved to give the desired output?

```
def equation(w,l):
    number = []
    while w > 0:
        number.append(min(l,w))
        l = max(l,w) - min(l,w)
    return number
```

Comment: where are you changing the value of w?

Comment: The code is only a function that is never called. Better show the complete code with function call and output creation.

Comment: Look at the implementations section of the wiki page for the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations), which is what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens in your code is that you don't change the value of w. As a result, you have an infinite loop. Something along those lines should work :

```
 def equation(w,l):
    # Exchange w and l if l is bigger than w
    if l > w:
        l, w = w, l
    number = []
    while w > 0:
        number.append(l)
        w, l = l, w-l
        if l > w:
            l, w = w, l
    return number
```

Comment: Thank you! I see now that I never changed the value of w and that was why I never got any output. I changed your code just a little bit further and added the if statement to the while loop. It works like a charm!